# Consumer CommitFailedException - time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have problem with kafka consumer which from time to time throws exception.

```
ERROR [*KafkaConsumerWorker] (Thread-125) [] Kafka Consumer thread 235604751 Exception while polling Kafka.: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:820) [kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:692) [kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1368) [kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1330) [kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:]
    at *.kafka.KafkaConsumerWorker.run(KafkaConsumerWorker.java:64) [classes:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
```

I can't find why is this happening, because the consumer is not processing any messages, while this exception occurs. These exceptions occurred 2 - 3 times daily. 
Some of my consumer configurations are as follow:

```
allow.auto.create.topics = true
auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
auto.offset.reset = latest
bootstrap.servers = [*]
check.crcs = true
client.dns.lookup = default
client.id = 52c94040-05d9-4b57-8006-afcc862f9b62
client.rack = 
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
enable.auto.commit = false
exclude.internal.topics = true
fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
group.id = TEST
group.instance.id = null
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
interceptor.classes = []
internal.leave.group.on.close = true
isolation.level = read_uncommitted
key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
max.poll.records = 10
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
```

Implementation:

```
  {
        logger.info("Kafka Consumer thread {} start", hashCode());
        Consumer<String, Message> consumer = null;


        try {
            consumer = KafkaConsumerClient.createConsumer();

            while (start) {
                try {
                    ConsumerRecords<String, Message> notifications =
                        consumer.poll(300000);

                    if (!notifications.isEmpty()) {
                        //processing.....
                    }

                    consumer.commitSync();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Kafka Consumer thread {} Exception while polling Kafka.", hashCode(), e);
                }
            }
            logger.info("Kafka Consumer thread {} exit", hashCode());
        } finally {
            if (consumer != null) {
                logger.info("Kafka Consumer thread {}  closing consumer.", hashCode());
                consumer.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I know that with this version of the kafka clinet, the heartbeatis sent from another thread which I guess that eliminates that the consumer spent too much time for processing (even that there is nothing to process). I guess that this is something with config timeoutes but can't find which exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to handle records in order, you should append events into an in memory queue from the consumer loop, then hand off that queue object into a completely new dequeue-ing Thread for the `processing...` logic

The error suggests whatever you're doing there is slow enough to stop and rebalance your consumer

I'd also recommend a higher level library that can handle backpressure such as the Connect / Streams API or Vertx or Smallrye Messaging or Akka Streams

Comment: It was not processing any data when the exception occurs.

Comment: It is not even entry in the processing code (there is only print statements which print the timestamp)

Comment: Then sounds like the synchronous commit is too long... Why not async?

Comment: I wnat to be sure that the message is commited.

Comment: Async will do that. It simply doesn't block

Comment: I saw some examples form kafka definitive guide and they commit everytime regardless if there is a message or not. Is it better to commitSync only If i have a message?

Comment: Well, that book is based on 0.10 api, and consumer thread logic has changed since then... The poll method is the only important part. Commits aren't needed until you want to actually move the "cursor" of the client forward. If you have no messages, obviously that's not necessary

Comment: You are right. THank you very much. I will try some things

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `Duration` of `Consumer#poll(Duration)` to lower than `max.poll.interval.ms` which is the maximum of time `Consumer` can stay idle before fetching more records. In [Kafka document](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#max.poll.interval.ms):

```
 If poll() is not called before expiration of this timeout, then the consumer is considered failed and the group will rebalance in order to reassign the partitions to another member
```

By the time you you commit your offset, your consumer is already failed, and partition had already revoked, group is rebalancing.

Comment: The ERROR is still there :( THe Duration comes from config file and I just copy/paste the value from max.poll.interval.ms (just for this example.)  Mine Duration is 20 sec. and max.poll.interval.ms is 300sec. so this is not the problem. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: @ROZZ the error is saying you're doing too much work against too many records between each poll. There's no single value for you to use - you'll have to play around with it

Comment: @OneCricketeer the exception occurred when there is no data to process.

Comment: @ROZZ then the poll loop should just continuously block. You shouldn't try to commit if you have no records either

Comment: @OneCricketeer hmm that's interesting I didn't think about that.